# how to set button's layout width at runtime?

Tags: android, layout

I'm making a remote-app, so I need a varying number of buttons, grouped by tableviews and tablerows.

I can create the fix ones (that must alwasy be available) at designtime via xml, making use of the layouts making all buttons fit on every resolution.

But there are buttons I have to create at runtime.
To make them behave the same way as the fixed ones, I need to assign the layout width, -height and -weight values.

I was searching the whole documentation, but there it is always done in XML, no word about runtime / matching routines.

Is this even possible??
How else could I create a to-all-sides-fitting grid of buttons?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Button should inherit [`setWidth(int pixels)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth%28int%29) from TextView (since it extends it). Have you tried using that? E.g.:

```
myButton.setWidth(100);
myButton.setHeight(50);
//Now myButton is 100px wide and 50px tall
```

Make sure you expand the drop down for "Inherited Methods" when you're looking for methods on the [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) page in the docs. You may also want to expand "Inherited Attributes".

Edit: Okay, I'll bite - if you want to retain screen independence you'll need to use dip units. The docs discuss this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), but it would be something like the following:

```
//Find screen density scale factor
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

int width = (int)(100 * scale) // Or whatever width you want
int height = (int)(50 * scale) // Or whatever height you want
myButton.setWidth(width);
myButton.setHeight(height);
```

**Note**: This is an example. This is not intended to be production code. You probably don't have a button named `myButton`. Please adapt this to your specific needs or read the linked documentation for more help, etc.

Comment: @Falmarri: I'm going to assume you mean that dip units are the best way to do this, though your comment is really too vague to be particularly helpful so I could be completely wrong. In any case, I'll add some scaling code, which I originally omitted due to the trivial nature of the question. I'd also suggest, though, that you consider posting more helpful comments, since one-off "don't do this" comments really don't contribute to the discussion, but that's up to you.